# getLastKnownLocation always returns null - API 23

Tags: android

I'm trying to make an application that works with the user's location.
First, I did a little test app to return the user's location at `getLastKnownLocation` assigning permission control requested by API 23.

The control of location is made by the condition

```
if (location != null){
        Log.i("LogX","Got Location!");
    } else{ Log.i("LogX","It has location");}
```

The problem is that at all times, returns "It has location". 
I think that should be something related to the use of `getLastKnownLocation`.

**My MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener{

LocationManager locationManager;
String provider;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    permissaoMapa();

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false);

    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    if (location != null){
        Log.i("LogX","Got Location!");
    } else{ Log.i("LogX","It has location");}
}


private void permissaoMapa(){
    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)){

        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},0);
        }
    }else {

    }
}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    for (int result : grantResults) {
        if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {

            return;
        } else {
            if (grantResults.length ==1) {

            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    Double lat = location.getLatitude();
    Double lon = location.getLatitude();

    Log.i("LogX",lat.toString());
    Log.i("LogX", lon.toString());


}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}

}
```

Comment: If no apps are holding location request call then lastknown location may get null. Try to use [FusedLocation API's](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi). [Here is an example](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/location/retrieve-current.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `getLastKnownLocation` work, I did the following steps:

- I open the terminal and typed the command "`telnet localhost 5554`" where 5554 refers to the AVD port
- Open the Maps application that comes installed on AVD
- Input the command line "`geo fix 12 45`" in the terminal . In this example you can type any latitude and longitude information.

There, after it managed to get the location.

[image]